# How can I use lsqnonlin with bounds for my solution excluding the interval limits?

Tags: matlab, optimization, solver, bounds

I need to solve a certain system whose solution values xa,xb are both within the ]0,1[ interval. And I also need xa to be different from xb
An example of what I pretend is below.
The main question is how do I set lb and ub between 0 and 1 excluding 0 and 1?

Main code:

```
x0=[0.001,0.9999]
lb=[0,0]
ub=[1,1]
parameters= load something or ask for input some values
fun = @(x)fobj(x,parameters)
[Solution]= lsqnonlin(fun,x0,lb,ub)
```

Objective function:

```
function [F] = fobj(x,parameters)
xa=x(1)
xb=x(2)
~Lot of code to obtain u1a, u1b, u2a, and u2b as a function of x and parameters.
The two equalities that I need to be zero:
error1=u1a-u1b
error2=u2a-u2b
F=[error1,error2]
end
```

Thank you very much,

Emanuel

Comment: Obviously I can define an epsilon sufficiently small e.g. 1E-10 and use [epsilon 1-epsilon]. I was just wondering if there is a way to consider any value except the limits so that following my example I would not left a 1E-11 solution out

Comment: Those are *bound-constraints* if you want to have *inequality constraints* use a different algorithm.... or follow @ECrespo's advice